# Snowflake json_extract_path_text does not accept a key with spaces

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The data coming into the warehouse is structured like this

{"Client ID":"1234567","client_name":"Kareem" }

when I use the function

```
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(COLUMN_NAME, 'Client ID')
```

it give me this error :

```
Invalid extraction path 'Client ID': invalid token at position 7.
```

is there another workaround to get the value for this key ? or for using this key with the function to get the value out of the JSON column ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per its documentation, the `JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT` function [follows the standard notation for object keys](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/json_extract_path_text.html#usage-notes). Keys that carry spaces are [required to be double-quoted](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#dot-notation), and the same applies here. The following works for your example:

```sql
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(COLUMN_NAME, '"Client ID"')
```

Comment: I have to admit, I never thought it would require both single and double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 COLUMN_NAME:"Client ID"
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The following does work, which is supposed to be close to equivalent.  My example assumes your values are a string, since that is the input of the function you were trying to use:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT '{"Client ID":"1234567","client_name":"Kareem" }' as json_string)
SELECT parse_json(json_string):"Client ID"
FROM x;
```